# How to integrate this integral from Fourier transform?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The question is from Fourier transform, but I don't know how to integrate this:

$$
\int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{jt}+e^{-jt}}{2} e^{\large-t(1+2\pi\alpha j)} dt.
$$

Comment: The image is unreadable.

Comment: Break it into two integrals. These integrals are fairly straightforward since they are integrals of exponential functions.

Comment: Jeez! Why didn't you zoom the image when screenshooting it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $j$ is an imaginary number, $j=\sqrt{-1}$.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{jt}+e^{-jt}}{2} e^{\large-t(1+2\pi\alpha j)} dt&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{\large-t(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)}\ dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{\large-t(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)}\ dt
\end{align}
Let $u=t(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)$ then $du=(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)\,dt$ and  $v=t(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)$ then $dv=(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)\,dt$.
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)}\int_0^\infty e^{\large-u}\ du+\frac{1}{2(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)}\int_0^\infty e^{\large-v}\ dv\\
=&\frac{1}{2(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)}+\frac{1}{2(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)}\\
=&\frac{1+2\pi\alpha j+1+2\pi\alpha j-j}{2(1+2\pi\alpha j-j)(1+2\pi\alpha j+j)}\\
=&\frac{1+2\pi\alpha j}{(1+2\pi\alpha j)^2-j^2}\\
=&\frac{1+2\pi\alpha j}{1+4\pi\alpha j-4\pi^2\alpha^2+1}\\
=&\frac{1+2\pi\alpha j}{2(1-2\pi^2\alpha^2+2\pi\alpha j)}
\end{align}
The final result agrees with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^\infty+\frac{e^{it}%2Be^{-it}}{2}+e^{-t%281%2B2\pi\alpha+i%29}+dt)

Comment: Fixed your formatting. Strictly speaking, there is a loophole in your argument. The change of variable $u = \text{const}_1 t$ or $v = \text{const}_2 t$ doesn't always work. It work this case because $\Re\text{const}_{1 \text{or} 2} > 0$. (No I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: Mr. @achillehui Thanks for your editing. I believe you're not the downvoter. Someone here targeted me yesterday. I got a lot of serial downvotes. Luckily, it's been reversed by the system. Thanks also for your suggestion about changing variables $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\dfrac{e^{jt}+e^{-jt}}{2}=\cos t$ and let $1+2\pi \alpha j=k$, then the integral you are dealing with is:
$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \cos t \,e^{-kt}\,dt=\frac{k}{k^2+1}$$
The above is easy to show using integration by parts. Substitute back $k=1+2\pi \alpha j$ to get:
$$I=\frac{1+2\pi \alpha j}{(1+2\pi \alpha j)^2+1}=\frac{1+2\pi \alpha j}{1+4\pi \alpha j-4\pi^2\alpha^2+1}=\frac{1+2\pi \alpha j}{2(1-2\pi^2 \alpha^2 +2\pi\alpha j)}$$
$\blacksquare$